# Create a new independent page

Tags: template

A site I'm working on (that you guys have helped me hugely on so far) requires a "splash" page which is completely different (and massively more complex) in layout to anything else on the site so I just want to create the page independently with HTML and CSS and then display this as a page. I guess it would be a completely new page template but not displaying any info from the CMS.

How do I go setting this up in the CMS and where do I need to place my template file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a [new page template](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates) and then when you add a new CMS page, instruct it to use this custom template. In the new template, you can call in what you wish to use and leave out everything you don't want to include.